# Parallel in Job SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have workflow in PowerShell and it runs functions in parallel. I am trying to do this in a SQL Server agent job, but I get an error, does anyone know how to defeat this?

```
workflow StartPar {
  parallel {
    fun1
    fun2
    fun3
  }
}

StartPar
```

Error in SQL Server Job:

> The job script encountered the following errors. These errors did not stop the script:
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
>
> at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
> at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
> at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.SqlPowerShell.GetErrorRecordMessage(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.SqlPowerShell.HandleAgentJob(RunspaceConfiguration config)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.SqlPowerShell.Main(String[] args).
>
> Process Exit Code 255.  The step failed.

If I start functions

```
fun1
fun2
fun3
```

I don't get any errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `fun1`, `fun2` and `fun3` do? Do they write to or read from shared/global variables? Please post the actual code if possible

Comment: They collect data from mysql tables, transfer it to a temporary table, where fun1 is where name = fun1, fun2 where name = fun2, etc. and then bulk copy to mssql server

Comment: Please provide functions with parameters. Problem can be with arguments scoping etc.
Your example looks fine.

Comment: I tried to do 
workflow Run-Parallel2 {

parallel {
1 + 1
  }
}

the error is the same, but everything works in ps, the error is in job. Maybe parallel doesn't work there?  
Is there another way to run functions in parallel?

Comment: @ziafok is the job step configured as a "PowerShell Job Step"? I suspect the `sqlps` logic in SQL Server doesn't support workflows, so maybe try putting your code in a separate script, and then in a regular command line job step launch `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\path\to\mysql_workflow_script.ps1`?

Comment: Thx! its work!!!!